# Xcode Archive doesn't recognize my developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am trying to publish my first app. So I need to archive and then verify and Upload my app.
But Xcode doesn't let me do that. After I archive the app, all the buttons are grayed out and it tells me to enroll in the Developer program BUT I am enrolled in the developer program. And I am in the last step of submitting my app.

Here's a picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er2Jo.png)

What do I need to do to be recognized by archiver. Or is there any other way?

Comment: You have a paid ($99) developer account?

Comment: Be sure to check your configuration in iTunes Connect as well.

Comment: yes I did pay $99

Comment: And you have a distribution certificate in your keychain?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Xcode->Preferences->Accounts and adding your developer credentials to a new account. Here is an aritcle detailing this process: [How to Add Account to Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/AddingYourAccounttoXcode/AddingYourAccounttoXcode.html)

Also check your project settings for the team and signing distribution. Here is more information on that: [Setting the Team for Signing and Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

Comment: Well, the problem is, I have already added my account. I can see it in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts.

Comment: I updated my answer but I think the next step is to check your setting in the project settings for the team and signing distribution information.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you bundle id, distribution profile and certificate is right.Then add you account in xcode like deanware said